# White Screen in React-Native Build from App Center

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I have the following issue with iOS builds distributed to my testers via Microsoft App Center.

After installing and opening, the app shows a login screen. After logging in, it takes you to a different screen asking for push notifications. These 2 screens work as intended and show properly.

Now, on that push notification screen it does not seem to matter if I enable them or not, in any case, the user is then pushed to the "App" Stack, which only shows a white screen all over the phone (no status bar). This App Stack is a different navigation stack (see below).

I do not have this issue anywhere else, not on the iPhone Simulator or a physical iPhone with `npm run ios`, not when building with xCode, not even when building a release build with xCode and running it on a physical device. This only occurs with builds from App Center.

The only code which comes to mind which could be relevant is below, but as mentioned, there are no issues anywhere else.

Root Navigator:

```js
const createRootNavigator = () => createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        // entry point, checks if logged in, pushes then either to Auth or App, works
        AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
        // login/signup, works as described above, pushes then to App
        Auth: AuthStack,
        // after pushing here, the white screen appears
        App,
    },
    // ...
}
```

And App is a tab navigator:

```js
const App = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: HomeStack,
        // ... more
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It was related to a different library which had some internal errors very early in the startup process of the app. I found out by building it for Android, on which the app wouldn’t even launch. Then I investigated crash logs on App Center. So this issue was not related to App Center, but rather code which was relevant on fresh installs.